# What shortkey CTRL + SPACE (context toggle) need for in Blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling, shortcut, gizmo

what does hotkey CTRL + SPACE (context toggle) for in Blender 2.8? In Blender 2.8 (legace 2.7 keymap) this hotkey is for function "space_data.show_gizmo_context" , but when I press it nothing happens. For example in 2.79 this bending used for hide gizmo, but in 2.8 nothing happends

Comment: Please make an effort to form the question clearly.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> causes the current view space to take up the entire window. This is true in 2.7 and 2.8.